# AddThis button + Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, addthis

I am trying to use AddThis button on a web page of mine, which you can share, like (facebook), and tweet (twitter) -

[image]

the AddThis code is pretty straight forward below,

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div id="share" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a><!---->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=xa-4cdb5be51dc49c98"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

but I don't understand - in the code above, where can I put the image or video url which I have uploaded and posted on my fb page? for instance the url below is the image from my facebook page that I want to track how many people like this picture through my website,

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150115644909972&set=a.10150115644754972.329183.55239684971

I have read through the documentation on AddThis but it doesnt explain this at all!
http://www.addthis.com/help/client-api#configuration-sharing

It points me to this,
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like#

again, this is a Facebook plugin, no used within AddThis. If I am using the Like button from the Facebook API, then I cannot use the AddThis plugin above, can I?

furthermore, The Like button from Faebook API seems to work on the Facebook page, but not an individual picture or video I uploaded/ posted on my Facebook Page, for instance, I tried this on my localhost, the picture on my Facebook Page won't collect the number of likes even though I have clicked the Like button on my screen.

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150115644909972&amp;set=a.10150115644754972.329183.55239684971" layout="button_count" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

so my main doubt on the Like button itself - does it work on facebook only or does it apply to the individual picture/ video on my facebook page? I tried to find this answer from the [facebook Like documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like#) but it doesn't explain anything about this.

it would be grateful if you have any idea. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" 
     expr:addthis:title='Photo' 
     expr:addthis:url='http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150115644909972&set=a.10150115644754972.329183.55239684971'> 
  <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a> 
  <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
  <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a><!---->
</div>
...
```

See also: http://www.addthis.com/help/widget-sharing#tagging

Answer (score 1):

You might get an error with the add this way to display the Facebook Like Button and IIS7.0.

I had the  problem yesterday and have posted a solution [here](http://ricardocovo.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/quick-fix-for-addthis-on-is7/).

Hope this helps,
Covo